# ajax post method treated as get by restclient

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got an url let’s say `abc` its type is post. if I try to call it as `$.ajax` method `post` it is showing method not allowed 405 error. it I sent by method `get` it is working fine but the business is not done how to solve the issue?

js code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (request){
       request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token)
    },
    success: function(res){
       console.log(res)
    },
    error: function(){
        JSON.parse(this.error.arguments[0].responseText).error.message.value 
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: it is post method beacuse one of my friend is using it as post in ui5 and got successful #Pranav C Balan

Comment: $.ajax({
                            type: "PUT",
                            url: url,
                            data: data,
                            beforeSend: function (request){

                                request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token)
                            },
                            success: function(res){
                                        console.log(res)   },
                            error: function(){ JSON.parse(this.error.arguments[0].responseText).error.message.value    },   dataType: "json"     });

Comment: PUT different from POST. You should try OPTIONS to see what is available on your server. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'method' instead of 'type'. Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (request){
       request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token)
    },
    success: function(res){
       console.log(res)
    },
    error: function(){
        JSON.parse(this.error.arguments[0].responseText).error.message.value 
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Or you can use the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

Comment: no difference what ever we use method/type i tried both but result is same

Answer (score 0):

> 405 Method Not Allowed

The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource. [405 Method Not Allowed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: i checked everything in network system in sap,ui5 the url and post method every thing is fine but while i am doing the same thing with ajax it is giving 405. #ozil

Comment: @AmaraBalakrishna Balakrishna can you share your `abc` url, does your url have post method exposed??

Comment: xxxxxxx.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/YEP_CUSTOMER_SRV/ykuDetailsset(Epkunnr='8000000123',Atnam='XFD_KU_PAYT_TERMS')